# Cascading dropdownlist in partial view with it's own view model in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to have a partial view that I can re-use in other views but I want it to be independent.

I have developed a sample application. In the view that I want to use this partial view, I need to populate partial view in `OnGet` and `OnPost` methods. I achieve something similar to what I want but it's like a small hack. You can check it here: https://github.com/dogukandemir/CascadingDropDownList

Is there any way to have an independent partial view and bind it to a model in the page that I want to re-use this partial view?

Let me give you some more details:

I want to have `SelectLocationView` with a view model named `SelectLocationViewModel`. This view model will handle populating Countries, Regions (by country) and Cities (by region).

In `SelectLocationView` I want to have 3 dropdownlists (countries, regions, cities). `SelectLocationViewModel.Countries` will be bound to `SelectLocationView` dropdownlist.

When I change the selection of the country, it'll bind selected country to `SelectedCountry` property of the view model. In `Index.cshtml.cs` I want to have `SelectLocationViewModel` as binding property and I want to bind that to the `SelectLocationView` partial view.

When I do operations on `SelectLocationView`, I want it to be reflected on `Index.cshtml.cs`'s `SelectLocationViewModel` property. After I'm done with my form and click a button in `Index.cshtml`, I want to get `SelectedCountry`, `SelectedRegion` and `SelectedCity` from thew `SelectLocationViewModel` property in `Index.cshtml.cs`.

Comment: When you include the partial view, you can specify a model for the partial.

Comment: @PoulBak with that approach, I need to add loading dropdownlist values logic to Index.cshtml.cs. I don't want to do that. I want to have it totally independent from parent view but at the same time I want parent view to access this partial view model. if you have a solution in your mind that I can't see from your comment, please contribute it to github repo in the question.

Comment: A model can be any object (not only the pages' model), for instance a class you create and fill with the properties needed for the partial view.

Comment: If you need the partial to load the dropdown values (from DB?) then you can just do that in the partial view like normally.

Comment: A partial page is just like a normal page, without the `@page` directive.

Comment: Then how you're going to load 2nd level dropdownlist? You should still do it in parent view, right?

Comment: And yes, I'm loading values from DB.

Comment: Well, the parent page does know what to load, right? You could also use `ViewData` to pass that info to partial page. Or may be I don't understand you at all.

Answer (score 0):

I did not connect to database,tried with hard coding as below:
in my controller:

```
public IActionResult SomeTest()
        {
            List<Country> CountryList = new List<Country>
            {
                new Country 
                { 
                    CountryId = 1, CountryName = "China",Cities=new List<City>()
                       {
                         new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
                         new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"}
                        },

                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryId = 2, CountryName = "American",Cities=new List<City>()
                       {
                         new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
                         new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
                        },

                },
            };
           
            List<City> Cities = new List<City>()
            {
                new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
                new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"},
                new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
                new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
            };
            var vm = new CountryCityViewModel() { Countries = CountryList, Cities = Cities };
            return View(vm);
        }

        public JsonResult GetCityList(int CountryId)
        {
            List<City> Cities = new List<City>()
            {
                new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
                new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"},
                new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
                new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
            };
            var targetcities = Cities.Where(x => x.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
            return new JsonResult(targetcities);
        }
```

My model:

```
public class CountryCityViewModel
    {
        public CountryCityViewModel() { Cities = new List<City>(); Countries = new List<Country>(); }
        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public Country() { Cities = new List<City>(); }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
```

in my View:

```
@model CountryCityViewModel
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            $.get("/Home/GetCityList", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                $("#CityId").empty();
                console.log(data);               
                
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var str1 = "";
                    var str2 = "";
                    $.each(item, function (j, val) {
                        console.log(j + ":" + val);
                        if (j == "cityId") { str1=val; };
                        if (j == "cityName") { str2 = val; };
                    });
                    var targetstring = "<option value=" + str1 + ">" + str2 +"</option>";
                    console.log(targetstring);
                    $("#CityId").append(targetstring);                    
                });
            });
        })
    });
</script>



<select asp-items='new SelectList(Model.Countries,"CountryId", "CountryName")' id="CountryId"></select>
@await Html.PartialAsync("Partial",Model.Cities)
```

my partialview:

```
@model List<City>
<select asp-items='new SelectList(Model,"CityId", "CityName")' id="CityId"></select>
```

The Result:
[image]

**Update:**
I migrate the codes to Razor Page and bind the model successfully:

```
public class SelectLocationViewModel
    {
        public Country SelectedCountry { get; set; }
        public City SelectedCity { get; set; }
    }
    public class SelectedCityModel : PageModel
    {
        public SelectedCityModel()
        {
            Cities = new List<City>();
            Countries = new List<Country>();
        }
        public SelectLocationViewModel selvm { get; set; }

        public List<Country> Countries { get; set; } 
        public List<City> Cities { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            List<Country> CountryList = new List<Country>
            {
                new Country
                {
                    CountryId = 1, CountryName = "China",Cities=new List<City>()
                       {
                         new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
                         new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"}
                       },

                },
                new Country
                {
                    CountryId = 2, CountryName = "American",Cities=new List<City>()
                       {
                         new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
                         new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
                        },

                },
            };

            List<City> Cities = new List<City>()
            {
                new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
                new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"},
                new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
                new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
            };
            this.Cities = Cities;
            this.Countries = CountryList;
        }        
        public void OnPost(SelectLocationViewModel selectvm)
        {
            
        }
        
    }
```

cshtml:

```
 @page
    @model CascadingDropDown.Pages.SelectedCityModel
    @{
    
    }
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#CountryId").change(function () {
                $.get("https://localhost:44357/GetCity", { CountryId: $("#CountryId").val() }, function (data) {
                    $("#CityId").empty();
                    console.log(data);
    
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        var str1 = "";
                        var str2 = "";
                        $.each(item, function (j, val) {
                            console.log(j + ":" + val);
                            if (j == "cityId") { str1=val; };
                            if (j == "cityName") { str2 = val; };
                        });
                        var targetstring = "<option value=" + str1 + ">" + str2 +"</option>";
                        console.log(targetstring);
                        $("#CityId").append(targetstring);
                    });
                });
            })
        });
    </script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#countryname").attr("value", "China");
            $("#cityname").attr("value", "Beijing");
            $("#CountryId").change(function () {
                var countryname = $("#CountryId").find(":selected").text();
                $("#countryname").attr("value", countryname);
            });
            $("#CityId").change(function () {
                var cityname = $("#CityId").find(":selected").text();
                $("#cityname").attr("value", cityname);
            });
        });
    </script>
    
    <form method="post">
        <select asp-items='new SelectList(@Model.Countries,"CountryId", "CountryName")' id="CountryId" name="SelectedCountry.CountryId"></select>
        <input id="countryname" name="SelectedCountry.CountryName" hidden />
        @await Html.PartialAsync("Partial", Model.Cities)
        <input type="submit" value="Sub" />
    </form>
```

PartialView:

```
@model List<City>
<select asp-items='new SelectList(Model,"CityId", "CityName")' id="CityId"name="SelectedCity.CityId"></select>
<input id="cityname" name="SelectedCity.CityName" hidden />
```

Getcity.cshtml.cs:

```
public JsonResult OnGet(int CountryId)
{
    List<City> Cities = new List<City>()
    {
        new City() { CityId=1,CountryId=1,CityName="Beijing"},
        new City() { CityId=2,CountryId=1,CityName="Shanghai"},
        new City() { CityId=3,CountryId=2,CityName="NewYork"},
        new City() { CityId=4,CountryId=2,CityName="Washington"}
    };
    var targetcities = Cities.Where(x => x.CountryId == CountryId).ToList();
    return new JsonResult(targetcities);
}
```

TestResult:
[image]

Comment: Are country and city values binded to view model inside parent view model? I could also done it like this but if you read details in my question, you can understand that this is not what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Dogukan Demir I've updated my answer,please check it